# CakePHP to Gmail Blocked

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, cakephp-2.0

I'm having trouble sending emails to Gmail accounts through CakePHP 2 *from a non-Gmail account. (EDIT)*

Error code from Gmail:
550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or fails to

SPF records are present in the server and I am able to send emails to Gmail using email software like Thunderbird.

Here is my code.

/app/Config/email.php

```
class EmailConfig {

public $email = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'mail.example.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'example@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'log' => false,
        'returnPath' => 'example@example.com',
);

}
```

After some Googling, I tried this way as well.

```
class EmailConfig {

public $email = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'mail.example.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'example@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'log' => false,
        'SMTPSecure' => 'starttls',
        'tls' => true,
        'context'=>array('ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
```

Controller

```
            $email = new CakeEmail('ap');

            $email->charset = 'ISO-2022-JP';

            $result = $email

            ->config(array('log' => 'emails'))

            ->to(array($this->request->data['Order']['mail']))

            ->bcc(array(Configure::read ('Mail.Bcc')))
            ->from(array(Configure::read ('Mail.FromMail')=> 'MyBusinessName'))
            ->subject($this->request->data['Order']['order_subject'])
            ->send($this->request->data['Order']['message']);

            if (!$result) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('MailSend Failed Retry Again '));
                return;
            } else {

                $this->OrderMailHistory->commit();
                $this->OrderStateHistory->commit();
                $this->Order->commit();

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'detail/', $this->request->data['Order']['id']));

            }

        }
```

Can someone please advise how we can get emails to be sent to Gmail?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you set up an App Password rather than just using your default Gmail password?

Comment: The sender email address is not a Gmail account and there is a password set up for that email, which is written in the code. But I'm not sure what you mean by an App password...

Comment: So did you research the terminology then? I find if I don't understand a particular word or concept, the internet normally knows: https://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+app+password ... basically you can't sign into Gmail with your regular google account password from an external application, you need to set up a separate authentication

Comment: `The sender email address is not a Gmail account`...that isn't going to work at all. With Gmail you must send from the address of the account, it's not a general mailserver. If you want to include details of another email account you could potentially put it into the reply-to field instead, or just in the message body.

Comment: Or are you trying to send _to_ Gmail from somewhere else? Sorry it wasn't totally clear

Comment: I am having problem sending TO Gmail from a non-Gmail email address. That is why I was not clear about the App password.

Comment: Sorry ok I've re-read it now and it's clearer, I think it was my mistake. Are you able to send to other non-Gmail addresses without a problem through PHP?

Comment: Thank you and yes, I can send emails to all other email addresses except Gmail.

Comment: Seems like gmail doesn't like the way your mailserver is sending the messages then, for some reason. I suggest maybe collaborating with the administrator of your mailserver.  Sorry its a bit beyond my personal expertise.